# PowerShell error: Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal. The hash literal was incomplete

Tags: powershell, aws-cloudformation, aws-powershell

I am trying to execute powershell command through cloudformation template. it is throwing below error from the log. and the same time same command is working if i execute manually from the windows powershell.

please help me! i am very new to the powershell requirements.

```
2023-02-13 06:24:11,459 [ERROR] Command 2-Reboot (powershell.exe -Command {Import-Module -name AWSPowerShell; [string]$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-se
conds" = "21600"} -Method PUT -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token; $instanceId = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token" = $token} -Method GET -Uri http://169.254.
169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id; Write-Output "reboot instance $instanceId through API"; Restart-EC2Instance -InstanceId $instanceId}) failed
2023-02-13 06:24:11,459 [DEBUG] Command 2-Reboot output: At line:1 char:84

+ ... WSPowerShell; [string]$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{X-aws-ec2 ...

+                                                                  ~

Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.

At line:1 char:84

+ ... WSPowerShell; [string]$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{X-aws-ec2 ...

+                                                                  ~

The hash literal was incomplete.

At line:1 char:231

+ ... atest/api/token; $instanceId = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{X-aws-ec2 ...

+                                                                  ~

Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.

At line:1 char:231

+ ... atest/api/token; $instanceId = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{X-aws-ec2 ...

+                                                                  ~

The hash literal was incomplete.

    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
```

i am trying to execute powershell command through cloudformation template. it is throwing above error from the log. and the same time same command is working if I execute manually from the windows PowerShell.

Comment: Please [format your code and error messages as code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm ... your code is actually broken do to the line breaks in it.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Olaf please help me to execute the command without breaks

Comment: I meant you have arbitrary line breaks here in the code you posted.